# JS how to return the amount of people that live in a city?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, city

I'm new to coding and have been given this question but I cannot seem to make my code work. Dose anyone have any suggestions?

This is the question I have been given:

This function receives an array of people objects in for format:

```
[{ name: 'Sandra', lives: { country: 'UK', city: 'Manchester' }, age: 32 }]
```

The function should return the count of people who live in the city of Valencia

This is the code I have made;

```
function countPeopleInValencia(people) {
let count = 0
for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  if (people.city[i] === 'Valencia') {
    count ++ }
  else {return 0}
  }
  return count
}
```

This is what my code will be run against;

```
describe("countPeopleInValencia", () => {
it("returns 0 when nobody is from Valencia", () => {
expect(
  countPeopleInValencia([
    {
      name: "Sandra",
      lives: { country: "UK", city: "Manchester" },
      age: 32
    },
    {
      name: "Sandrella",
      lives: { country: "Spain", city: "Bilbao" },
      age: 32.5
    }
  ])
).to.equal(0);
  });
  it("returns the length of the array when everyone is from Valencia",   () => {
  expect(
  countPeopleInValencia([
    {
      name: "Cassandra",
      lives: { country: "Spain", city: "Valencia" },
      age: 32.5
    },
    {
      name: "Cassandrella",
      lives: { country: "Spain", city: "Valencia" },
      age: 35.55
    }
  ])
).to.equal(2);
 });
it("returns the number of people who are actually from the fair city of Valencia", () => {
expect(
  countPeopleInValencia([
    {
      name: "Melissandra",
      lives: { country: "Spain", city: "Valencia" },
      age: 55.5
    },
    {
      name: "Melissandrella",
      lives: { country: "Spain", city: "Valencia" },
      age: 55.555
    },
    {
      name: "Keith",
      lives: { country: "UK", city: "Newport Pagnell" },
      age: 2
    }
  ])
).to.eql(2);
expect(
  countPeopleInValencia([
    {
      name: "Imeldarina",
      lives: { country: "Spain", city: "Valencia" },
      age: 15.2
    },
    {
      name: "Bob",
      lives: { country: "Wales", city: "Abertillery" },
      age: 555555555555.555
    },
    {
      name: "Terry",
      lives: { country: "England", city: "Newport Pagnell" },
      age: 0.00000002
    }
  ])
).to.equal(1);
});
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: That `else { return 0; }` is wrong. You don't want to return from the function until you've actually been through the entire list. The `return count;` at the end is the only `return` you need.

Comment: `return people && people.filter(i => (i.lives && i.lives.city === 'Valencia')).length;`?... http://jsfiddle.net/briosheje/k9yc5dLz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current code you return the value of count as soon as you find a person who is not in the city you want to count

```
function countPeopleInValencia(people) {
    let count = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        if (people.city[i] === 'Valencia') {
             count ++ 
        }
    }
    return count
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Along with moving the count outside the for loop, you should correct

```
people.city[i]
```

to

```
people[i]['lives']['city']
```

Your function:

```
function countPeopleInValencia(people) {
  let count = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    if (people[i]['lives']['city'] === 'Valencia') {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count
}
```